# Can I annotate on a OneToMany relationship for performance?

Tags: django, performance, django-aggregation

I have the following simplified models.

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    ...

class ServiceLogs(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='logs', ...)
    who_did = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    role_played = models.CharField(choices=(('CA','CA'),
                                            ('CO', 'CO'),
                                            ('TO', 'TO')), ...)
```

I know I can find out who played what role by calling 
`<service obj>.logs.filter(role='CA')`, but this approach hits the database 3 times per object given I have 3 roles.

I was reading the documentation about aggretation and annotation, but all the examples use numeric values like Sum, Avg, etc. I tried using `Q` for lookups, but Django complains with the message `'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'output_field'`

Can I make this query more efficient so I hit the database once per object?

Comment: Why not use `__in`? `<service_obj>.logs.filter(role_played__in=['CA', 'CO', 'TO'])`

Comment: I wanted to split who played what role and save it on a separated field like this: `<service_obj>.logs.annotate(role_ca=Q(role_played='CA'), role_co=Q(role_played='CO'), role_to=Q(role_played='TO'))`